# Why do my complex QGIS labels display fine in Odense 3.20.0 but not in Bialowieza 3.22.10 or 3.26 Buenos Aires?

Tags: qgis, labeling

[Here](https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=FhKQFemTFIJzn5ywFPMHvtCTWJMlhUAoxeQEKPe-2F76gG-2BYFcTwDlMA51-2Bnagr5RFLScMV5rWGBCpZns29t3UVdDwvXevt0BLrXvJhS0NQ9A-3D4YAN_wArwv6CZGcWRKvlXtOXCg-2BeW30l1rYW5w2C3BW5C0SvjyDPnrmNh3XH9-2F1XnsFvR3WfNxbjeJvVvmJhT29gOFAu7D8bK5tDiuS-2BSJR3SsqVVGmTOmXGxFR5RW5RUTx9efQtgU5cKZWF18qs8gepkA8bnFvmkDmnTpsisUo3aRYrYK6dsTo5WBTFBA2DwbFKiX2uTEq9sGo45s8RF5MOav26JwgiZ0jAc-2BgpInNxMLE95pTZZBoyD4NwoxduuHkScMy2jcAOCTOEW5jSK1aqiHEIuB4kNP-2FO0ITsh-2BOn4IPO24Idk5fKs3arWum2sgUZEEd5stgAOxJoSff3SxxoXG3MY64FseM7No0ZGN1ZZjGGFlb90XEORjQwuPqX8a0-2BhtLfG1wvU3TnTlAnFOR5AJAT85w64xPOM9vvWYBjGxfw4kjL38l9ADm-2Ft5epAmH36QZm7Je52bIy3cT5w6t5-2FbKRhmPwXYGW0PIHkTE42AYs34rihkLB2p2f-2FACEh6AYmIK7hwTivBiZdF4scwrPptYrCO11JSJQrUkSbH4nlkTc-3D__;!!C5rN6bSF!Ckg5UzQLGEEVcUCox_2PDygwpaNiCRpp51uiMWxmfEea47dGLJ9kVB47YI6rHIqhhuC8w4q-t-XvylVysJvRxi7k4AofBT4N0CtyIqlWFLCWiDmstw$) is a link to the layers & project. The project is located in the folder Demonstration Farm Data (V2).

I am a real amateur at this stuff. Will study up on custom variables.

I have developed 3 simple tables showing what proportions of a farm have been set aside for woodlots, shelterbelts and biodiversity purposes. The 3 tables were built using QGIS 3.20.2 Odense.  The tables involve numerous expressions built into the attributes table (field calculator & virtual fields) and labelling expressions. The data, contents and location of the tables involves accessing a variety of layers. All 3 tables display okay in Odense but not in Bialowieza 3.22.10 or Buenos Aires 3.26 and produce the following error message:  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uG1S.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/D51Qg.jpg
enter image description here
[image]

> [image: Blockquote]

Here is a bit more information on how the tables are meant to work:
To display one or more of the tables the User needs:
Plot the boundary of one or more farms (or update the attributes of an existing farm boundary)
Select “Display data just for this farm” (Yes/No)
Select “Display summary table over this farm” (Yes/No)
Update the whole farm plan including current and future changes
The user can then turn on one or more tables by placing a tick against the relevant layer

How do the tables work?
The content and layout of the table (or label) is dictated by a series of expressions written into the label “Value” field. The labels are formatted to one decimal place and in the case of the Carbon Summary lengthened and shorten depending on what data is available.
The location of the table is based on coordinates built into the label and sourced from the centroid of the relevant farm boundary feature.

Carbon Summary table
The Carbon Summary table gets most of its data directly from the individual Woody Vegetation layers such as Woodlot, Biodiversity area, Plantation/shelterbelt and Regeneration area. These layers calculate the area of relevant features after checking the user settings in the Farm Boundary layer. The Carbon Summary table also gets data directly from the Farm Boundary layer (Area_T) and from the Summary Expression layer (Woody, Woody_P)

Farm Summary and Farm Summary Proposed tables
These tables collect data in a similar fashion from a number of other layers including Farm Boundary layer (Area_T) and the Summary Expression layer (Woody, Woody_P, Laneways, Laneways_P, Degraded, Grazing, Grazing_P, Other, Other_P, Grand_T)

Summary Expression layer
The Summary Expression layer gets its data from numerous other individual layers such Woodlot, Plantation/shelterbelt, Laneways, Erosion areas, Salt areas, Dams, Stock containment areas.
These individual layers then check to see if their features are inside the relevant farm boundary in the case where “Display data just for this farm” = “Yes” or simply sums the area of all features where “Display data just for this farm” = “No”

Below is a list of all the expressions used to produce the 3 tables (although they are probably too messy to be of use):

```
Attribute table expressions
Area
format_number($area,1)
Area_T
if(if(sum(CASE WHEN "Summ_Table" = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>'0', if("Summ_Table" = 'Yes', $area, NULL), sum($area))is null,0,
format_number(if(sum(CASE WHEN "Summ_Table" = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>'0', if("Summ_Table" = 'Yes', $area, NULL), sum($area)),1))Carbon_S
"Which table to display?" = 'Carbon summary' AND $AREA>12
Centroid_X
if(if("Place_T_H" = 'Yes',x_max(centroid($geometry)),null)is null,0,
if("Place_T_H" = 'Yes',x_max(centroid($geometry)),null))
Centroid_Y
if(if("Place_T_H" = 'Yes',y_max(centroid($geometry)),null)is null,0,if("Place_T_H" = 'Yes',y_max(centroid($geometry)),null))
Layer - Summary expressions
Woody
format_number((if(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"Farm_TT")is null,0,aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"Farm_TT"))+if(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"Farm_TT")is null,0,aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"Farm_TT"))+
if(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"Farm_TT")is null,0,aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"Farm_TT"))+if(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"Farm_TT")is null,0,aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"Farm_TT"))),1)
Woody_P
format_number((if(aggregate('Woodlot_New','sum',"Farm_T")is null,0,aggregate('Woodlot_New','sum',"Farm_T"))+if(aggregate('Biodiversity area_New','sum',"Farm_T")is null,0,aggregate('Biodiversity area_New','sum',"Farm_T"))+
if(aggregate('Regeneration area_New','sum',"Farm_T")is null,0,aggregate('Regeneration area_New','sum',"Farm_T"))+if(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt_New','sum',"Farm_T")is null,0,aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt_New','sum',"Farm_T"))),1)
Laneways
format_number(if(aggregate('Laneway polygon','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Laneway polygon','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Laneway polygon','sum',"All Farms")),1)Other
format_number(if(aggregate('Building','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Building','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Building','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Dam','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Dam','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Dam','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Stock containment area','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Stock containment area','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Stock containment area','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"All Farms")),1)
Degraded
format_number(if(aggregate('Erosion area','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Erosion area','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Erosion area','sum',"All_Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Rehabilitated erosion','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Rehabilitated erosion','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Rehabilitated erosion','sum',"All_Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Salt area','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Salt area','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Salt area','sum',"All_Farms")),1)
Laneways_P
format_number(if(aggregate('Laneway polygon_New','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Laneway polygon_New','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Laneway polygon_New','sum',"All_Farms")),1)
Degraded
format_number(if(aggregate('Erosion area','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Erosion area','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Erosion area','sum',"All_Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Rehabilitated erosion','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Rehabilitated erosion','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Rehabilitated erosion','sum',"All_Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Salt area','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Salt area','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Salt area','sum',"All_Farms")),1)
Other
format_number(if(aggregate('Building','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Building','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Building','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Dam','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Dam','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Dam','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Stock containment area','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Stock containment area','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Stock containment area','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"All Farms")),1)
Other_P
format_number(if(aggregate('Building_New','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Building_New','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Building_New','sum',"All_Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Dam_New','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Dam_New','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Dam_New','sum',"All_Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"One Farm")+aggregate('Land class 8','sum',"All Farms"))
+
if(aggregate('Stock containment area_New','sum',"Area")is null,0, aggregate('Stock containment area_New','sum',"One_Farm")+aggregate('Stock containment area_New','sum',"All_Farms")),1)
Grazing
format_number(aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Area_T") - "Woody" - "Laneways" - "Degraded" - "Other",1)
Grazing_P
format_number(aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Area_T") - "Woody_P" - "Laneways_P" - "Degraded" - "Other_P",1)
Grand_T
format_number("Woody" + "Laneways" + "Degraded" + "Other" + "Grazing",1)

Layer - Farm summary
F_Cords_X
aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Centroid_X")
F_Cords_Y
aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum', "Centroid_Y")
Area_T
format_number(aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Area_T"),1)

Layer - Farm summary proposed
F_Cords_X
aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Centroid_X")
F_Cords_Y
aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum', "Centroid_Y")
Area_T
format_number(aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Area_T"),1)

Layer - Carbon summary
F_Cords_X
aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Centroid_X")
F_Cords_Y
aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum', "Centroid_Y")
Area_T
format_number(aggregate('Farm boundary', 'sum',"Area_T"),1)

Layers - Woody vegetation
Layers:  Woodlot, Biodiversity area, Plantation/Shelterbelt, Regeneration area
New_All F 
if(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,if("Age" = 'New', $area,0),0)is null, 0,
format_number(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,if("Age" = 'New', $area,0),0),1))
Replaces NULL value with 0 then checks for a “Yes” (single farm VS all farms summary table) and “New” feature” to returns TOTAL area.
Grow_All F
if(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,if("Age" = 'Growing', $area,0),0)is null, 0,
format_number(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,if("Age" = 'Growing', $area,0),0),1))
Mat_All F
if(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,if("Age" = 'Mature', $area,0),0)is null, 0,
format_number(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,if("Age" = 'Mature', $area,0),0),1))
New_One F
if(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is True,'1', '0') AND (CASE WHEN "Age" = 'Mature' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'New' THEN '1' WHEN "Age" = 'Growing' THEN '0' END= 1),$area,'0')is null,0,
format_number(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is True,'1', '0') AND (CASE WHEN "Age" = 'Mature' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'New' THEN '1' WHEN "Age" = 'Growing' THEN '0' END= 1),$area,'0'),1))
Replaces NULL value with 0 then checks to see if current feature is in nominated property (“Yes”) and has the nominated “Age” and returns FEATURE area.
Grow_One F
if(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is True,'1', '0') AND (CASE WHEN "Age" = 'Mature' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'New' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'Growing' THEN '1' END= 1),$area,'0')is null,0,
format_number(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is True,'1', '0') AND (CASE WHEN "Age" = 'Mature' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'New' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'Growing' THEN '1' END= 1),$area,'0'),1))
Mat_One F
if(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is True,'1', '0') AND (CASE WHEN "Age" = 'Mature' THEN '1' WHEN "Age" = 'New' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'Growing' THEN '0' END= 1),$area,'0')is null,0,
format_number(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is True,'1', '0') AND (CASE WHEN "Age" = 'Mature' THEN '1' WHEN "Age" = 'New' THEN '0' WHEN "Age" = 'Growing' THEN '0' END= 1),$area,'0'),1))
New_T
"New_One F" + "New_All F"
Growing_T
"Grow_All F"+"Grow_One F"
Mat_T
"Mat_All F" + "Mat_One F"
Farm_TT
"New_One F" + "Grow_One F" + "Mat_One F"
+ "New_All F" + "Grow_All F" + "Mat_All F"
Links Layers: Farm boundary
Links Fields:  Summ_Table, Age

Layers - Woody vegetation (New)
Layers:  Woodlot_New, Biodiversity area_New, Plantation/Shelterbelt_New, Regeneration area_New
Area
if("Type" is null,0,format_number($Area,1))
Area_T
format_number(sum("Area"),1)
One_F
if(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is true,'1', '0')= '1', ($area),'0')is null,0,
format_number(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_Table = 'Yes')is true,'1', '0')= '1', ($area),'0'),1))
All_F
if(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,($area),0)is null,0,
format_number(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,($area),0),1))
Farm_T
format_number(("One_Farm" + "All_Farms"),1)

Layers – Non-Grazing
Layers:  Dam, Laneways, SCA, Buildings, Land class 8, Dam New etc
Fields:   New_All Farms, Growing_All Farms, Mature_All Farms
Area
format_number($area,1)
One Farm
format_number(if(if(overlay_intersects('Farm boundary', filter:=Summ_table = 'Yes'),'1', '0')= '1', ($area),'0'),1)
Checks to see if current feature is in nominated property (“Yes”) and returns area.
Links Layers: Farm boundary
Links Fields:  Summ_Table, Age
All Farms
format_number(if(aggregate('Farm boundary','count',"Summ_Table","Summ_Table"='Yes')= 0,($area),0),1)Checks for a “Yes” (single farm VS all farms summary table) and “New” feature” to returns area.
Links Layers: Farm boundary
Links Fields:  Summ_Table, Age
Farm_T
format_number(("One Farm" + "All Farms"),1)
Sums woody vegetation for use in Farm boundary Woody

Labelling expressions
Label – Farm Summary
'Please ensure you have read the "Background notes"' ||  '\n'  || '              before using the summary tables' ||  '\n'  ||
'----------------------------------------------------------------' ||   '\n'  || 
'SUMMARY - EXISTING' ||  '\n' ||'Approximate area and percent of farm' ||  '\n'  || 

'Grazing                         ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grazing") ,1)||'ha          '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grazing")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||

'Laneways                      ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Laneways") ,1)||'ha              '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Laneways")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||

'Woody vegetation           ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Woody") ,1)||'ha            '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Woody")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||


'Land degradation            ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Degraded") ,1)||'ha              '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Degraded")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||
  
'Other areas                    ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Other") ,1)||'ha              '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Other")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'  || 

 'TOTAL                           ' || aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grand_T") || 'ha          '
 
  ||format_number((aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grand_T")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100),1) || '%'

Label - Farm Summary Proposed
'Please ensure you have read the "Background notes"' ||  '\n'  || '              before using the summary tables' ||  '\n'  ||
'----------------------------------------------------------------' ||   '\n'  || 
'SUMMARY - PROPOSED' ||  '\n' ||'Approximate area and percent of farm' ||  '\n'  || 
'Grazing                         ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grazing_P") ,1)||'ha          '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grazing_P")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||
'Laneways                      ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Laneways_P") ,1)||'ha              '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Laneways_P")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||
'Woody vegetation          ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Woody_P") ,1)||'ha               '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Woody_P")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||
'Land degradation           ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Degraded") ,1)||'ha               '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Degraded")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%'|| '\n'  ||
'Other areas                   ' || format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Other_P") ,1)||'ha               '  ||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Other_P")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'  || 
 'TOTAL                         ' || aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grand_T") || 'ha            '
   ||format_number((aggregate('Summary expressions','mean',"Grand_T")/aggregate('Farm boundary','sum',"Area_T")*100),1) || '%'

Label – Carbon Summary
'Please ensure you have read the "Background notes"' ||  '\n'  || '              before using the Summary tables' ||  '\n'  ||  '------------------------------------------------------------------------------'  || '\n'  ||  
'CARBON SUMMARY' ||  '\n' ||'Area and percent of farm            ' ||  '\n'  || 
 concat('Woodlot (new)                           ' || format_number(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"New_T"),1) ||' ha           '   || format_number(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"New_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'  ,
    'Woodlot (growing)                      ' ||format_number(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"Growing_T"),1)  || 'ha            '||format_number(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"Growing_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||   '\n' ,
    'Woodlot (mature)                       ' || format_number(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"Mature_T"),1) ||'ha            ' ||format_number(aggregate('Woodlot','sum',"Mature_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'  ,
  'Woodlot (proposed)                    ' || format_number(aggregate('Woodlot_New','sum',"Farm_T"),1) || 'ha            ' || format_number(aggregate('Woodlot_New','sum',"Farm_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' || '\n'  , 
 'Biodiversity (new)                       ' || format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"New_T"),1) ||'ha            '  ||format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"New_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'   , 
    'Biodiversity (growing)                  ' ||format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"Growing_T"),1)  || 'ha            '||format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"Growing_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n' ,
    'Biodiversity (mature)                   ' || format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"Mature_T"),1) ||'ha            ' ||format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area','sum',"Mature_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'  , 'Biodiversity (proposed)                ' || format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area_New','sum',"Farm_T"),1) || 'ha            ' || format_number(aggregate('Biodiversity area_New','sum',"Farm_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n' , 
 'Plantation (new)                          ' || format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"New_T"),1) ||'ha            '  ||format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"New_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||   '\n'   , 
  'Plantation (growing)                     ' ||format_number(
  aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"Growing_T"),1)  || 'ha            '||format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"Growing_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||   '\n' , 
  'Plantation (mature)                      ' || format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"Mature_T"),1) ||'ha            ' ||format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt','sum',"Mature_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' || '\n'  ,
 'Plantation (proposed)                   ' || format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt_New','sum',"Farm_T"),1) || 'ha            ' ||format_number(aggregate('Plantation/shelterbelt_New','sum',"Farm_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%'  ||  '\n'  ,
 'Regeneration (new)                      ' || format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"New_T"),1) ||'ha            '  || format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"New_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' || '\n'   
  'Regeneration (growing)                 ' ||format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"Growing_T"),1)  || 'ha            '||format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"Growing_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||   '\n' , 
    'Regeneration (mature)                  ' || format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"Mature_T"),1) ||'ha            ' || format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area','sum',"Mature_T"  )/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%' ||  '\n'  ,
  'Regeneration (proposed)               ' || format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area_New','sum',"Farm_T"),1) || 'ha            ' ||format_number(aggregate('Regeneration area_New','sum',"Farm_T")/"Area_T"*100,1)  || '%'  ||  '\n' , 
 'TOTAL                                         ' ||format_number(if(aggregate('Summary expressions', 'mean', "Woody_P")is null,0,aggregate('Summary expressions', 'mean', "Woody_P")),1) || 'ha          '||format_number(aggregate('Summary expressions', 'mean', "Woody_P")/mean (sum("Area_T"))*100,1)  || '%')



Label - Background Notes
Filter:  if("Notes" = 'Yes',if("Inside" = 'True','bcg', 'yes'),'no')
Label:  '*BACKGROUND NOTES
The summary tables provide a rough guide to the relative'
 ||  '\n'  || 
'proportions of various land uses on the farm. The tables'
 ||  '\n'  || 
'should not be used for financial or business purposes.'
 ||  '\n'  || '\n'  ||    

'To get the best results you need to map (and save) the following: 
1.  Farm boundary
2.  Laneways (Laneway polygon)
3.  Areas of woody vegetation
4.  Areas affected by land degradation
5.  Other areas including stock containment areas, dams,'
 ||  '\n'  || 
'buildings and non-agricultural land (Land class 8)' || 
 '\n'  ||  '\n'  || 
'WARNING
Significant errors can occur if any of the above areas overlap on' ||  '\n'  ||'the map. For example the area of "Grazing" displayed below will' ||  '\n'  || 'be will be reduced by the area of overlap.' ||  '\n'  || '\n'  ||  '* To turn off these notes change the Farm boundary Display Background Notes attribute to "No"'
Displays background notes
Links Layers: Farm boundary
Links Fields:  Display Background Notes
```

Comment: It's a whole bunch of text to read - this makes it difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Can you share project + layers for testing?

Comment: As the error message says, you seem to have a lot of nested expressions. That ends up in a whole mess and it's difficult to get an overwiev or find errors. You should better create everything possible as an attribute (or custom variable) and then use much lighter expressions to generate your output.

Comment: Hi Babel, thanks for your help. I now have my complex QGIS labels displaying in both Bialowieza 3.22.10 and Buenos Aires 3.26. After lots of trial and error I narrowed down the issue to one layer. Replacing the expression: 

format_number(if(sum(CASE WHEN "Summ_Table" = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>'0', if("Summ_Table" = 'Yes', $area, NULL), ($area)),1)) 

with

format_number(if(count("Summ_Table", filter:="Summ_Table"='Yes')>0,if("Summ_Table" ='Yes',$area,0),$area),1) 

appears to have fixed the problem. Not sure why it worked okay in Odense. Seems like function “Sum” was the problem.